# Dependencies issue with spring-security-core plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-security

I'm trying to install spring-security-core plugin to my project, but it seems that plugin files can't be found in any of the repositories.

I added this line to BuildConfig file's plugin section:

```
    compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
```

After running grails compile command I'm getting following errors (shortened):

```
        ==== ebrRelease: tried

          http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-core-3.2.0.RC1.pom

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-core;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-core.jar:

          http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-core-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== ebrExternal: tried

          http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-core-3.2.0.RC1.pom

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-core;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-core.jar:

          http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-core-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== grailsCentral: tried

          http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-core-3.2.0.RC1.pom

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-core;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-core.jar:

          http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_3.2.0.RC1/grails-spring-security-core-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== mavenCentral: tried

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-core-3.2.0.RC1.pom

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-core;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-core.jar:

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-core-3.2.0.RC1.jar

                module not found: org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1

        ==== grailsHome: tried

          C:\dev\springsource\grails-2.2.3\bin\../lib/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/ivy-3.2.0.RC1.xml

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-web.jar:

          C:\dev\springsource\grails-2.2.3\bin\../lib/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/jars/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar

          C:\dev\springsource\grails-2.2.3\bin\../lib/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/bundles/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== grailsHome: tried

          C:\dev\springsource\grails-2.2.3\bin\..\src\libs/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.xml

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-web.jar:

          C:\dev\springsource\grails-2.2.3\bin\..\src\libs/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== grailsHome: tried

          C:\dev\springsource\grails-2.2.3\bin\..\dist/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.xml

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-web.jar:

          C:\dev\springsource\grails-2.2.3\bin\..\dist/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== grailsHome: tried

          C:\dev\springsource\grails-2.2.3\bin\../plugins/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.pom

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-web.jar:

          C:\dev\springsource\grails-2.2.3\bin\../plugins/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== ebrRelease: tried

          http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.pom

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-web.jar:

          http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== ebrExternal: tried

          http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.pom

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-web.jar:

          http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== grailsCentral: tried

          http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-web/tags/RELEASE_3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.pom

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-web.jar:

          http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-web/tags/RELEASE_3.2.0.RC1/grails-spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar

        ==== mavenCentral: tried

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.pom

          -- artifact org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1!spring-security-web.jar:

          http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.2.0.RC1/spring-security-web-3.2.0.RC1.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.springframework.security#spring-security-core;3.2.0.RC1: not found

                :: org.springframework.security#spring-security-web;3.2.0.RC1: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.0.RC1
- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.RC1
```

I also added the ebr() repository to the repositories list. But that didn't change anything.

What could be done to resolve this problem and download the plugin correctly?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need extra repository:

```
mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
```

See announce: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-2-0-RC-release-td4649905.html

Comment: add the above line under the repositories section in your BuildConfig.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Check (preferable from the same console) every URL grails is trying to download

```
curl --verbose  http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_2.0-RC2/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom
```

In my case I have detected that **http://grails.org** repository has been moved to **https://repo.grails.org**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 01:59:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
expires=Sat, 05-Mar-16 01:59:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.grails.org; HttpOnly
Location: https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins-releases-local/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/2.0-RC2/spring-security-core-2.0-RC2.pom

Good luck!